# Prevent content scraping that automatically post from one website to another

Tags: cloudflare, feeds, scraper-sites, spam-bots

Basically, my website is running on WordPress platform and we publish posts on regular basis. As soon as we publish a post, in a few minutes time it gets posted on their website as well

The worst part is that they are ranking for the copy paste content. How can i prevent this website from automatically posting our posts on their website. I tried two things

1. Blocked their website ip address on cloudflare to access the feeds of our website
2. I also tried blocking all the bots except user agents(googlebot and bingbot) to access the feeds, like how it is on this link https://www.techbusinessnews.com.au/rss-feed-scraper-websites-and-how-to-stop-them/

But the above two things unable to stop them from doing so, Any solution would greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) If it's an automated process, you can try to figure out how it arrives to your site:

1. Post a sample publication after hours (i.e., 3am)
2. Check your competitor at what time they reposted
3. Identify in your logs all accesses done to that particular URL between those 2 times. Try to identify User-Agents, IP addresses, or any particular behavior that can identify them.
4. Block that pattern in Cloudflare

B) A different approach can be to inject a canonical tag in your post. If they happen to import the tag, it will tell search engines that the original posting is yours.

C) The other approach is going the legal way.

1. Contact the owner, ask them to stop.
2. Send a cease-and-desist letter
3. File a DMCA take down notice
4. File a Google DMCA notice directly
5. Report them to the abuse department at their server's host.

Comment: I have solved it by checking the Access logs, they are using different IP addresses to perform these activities(not the actual website IP address)....these spammers usually have 'HEAD' request instead of GET(we can also see their hidden website in the device section)